# No dash, no launcher in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, launcher, 14.10, unity-dash

I am presented with the same issue that the one described [here](/a/76951/175814): no dash and no launcher upon login.

I am creating a new question though because the solution doesn't resolve the problem.

Note that I am able to login Ubuntu Flashback where everything is normal.

Comment: Which solution did you try? Was there an error message of some sort?

Comment: @DavidFoerster The first one, with ccsm. There was no error message.

Comment: Do you realise that this answer is from 2011? Please look at one of the later answers, specifically those that say they refer to 14.04 or 14.10 or that have comments confirming they work in those releases.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sure but none of them is specifically targeted at 14.10

Comment: To downvoter: please be specific about what is incorrect here, or shows no research effort.

Comment: what does `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` report?

Comment: @doug `OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.3.0` and a bunch of `yes`

Comment: Log in to a guest session & see if unity/compiz loads there.

Comment: @doug thank you that was useful. Unity/compiz loads in a guest session.

Comment: Well then you know now it's something in your config. Maybe try a reset compiz & restart unity command. Provide yourself a means open a terminal while in the *ubuntu(unity) session*. Login, open a terminal, then 2 commands. `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` followed by `setsid unity` (- if need be log into flashback session & place the terminal launcher on the Desktop., then log into ubuntu session, ect.

Comment: @doug I could do what you suggest, but it doesn't work. `compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.`

Comment: It may be easier for you to resolve this in an interactive forum like Ubuntu forums, anyway - log into ubuntu session, open a terminal & go `ccsm`. The first 3 lines should be `Backend     : gsettings` `Integration : true`, `Profile     : unity`. A Profile of Default would be wrong. So check that first. If profile is unity then try enabling `OpenGl`, `Composite`, `Ubuntu unity plugin` ect. If profile isn't unity then go to `Preferences > Profile`, choose unity, then go back & enable mentioned plugins

Comment: @doug definitely! But I didn't imagine it would be such a mess. Anyway now it works! If you feel like reformatting your comments in an answer, I would gratefully accept it.

Comment: Not the OP but I also can't run dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ ... Cannot auto launch d-bus without X11 $DISPLAY