# Upgrade to 14.10 and video drivers... no menus or dash

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher, 14.10, unity-dash

Finally managed to get a 14.10 install to stick, but there's no side menu and no top-right power button or menu there. If I launch a program (like use a folder to navigate to and launch a media file), the program will work, but there will be no menu.

Ctrl-Alt-T doesn't launch the Terminal, either. I'm stumped.

I've tried instructions like these: [solution 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/76951#76951)

But ccsm gives me this error:

[image: ccsm error]

And with [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572438/no-dash-no-launcher-in-ubuntu-14-10)

I get this error:

[image: Dconf error]

I'be also tried installing unity-tweak-tool and --restore from the Alt-F2 terminal (no regular terminal) and it does nothing.

Help?

[image: Desktop with no menus]